# Return signal in Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

How I can return signal in Linux **in assembler**? I want return SIGALRM (#14 signal).

```
global _start

_start:
    mov    eax, 01h
    mov    ebx, 0xE
    int    80h
```

But:

`Runtime error: time: 0 memory: 140 signal:-1`

I know I'm doing it wrong, but how I can return any Linux signal?

Comment: What do you mean by "return signal"?

Comment: You mean "return a signal number"? Just compile this in C (with `gcc -O3 -S -o /dev/stdout -masm=intel`) and check the result: `#include <signal.h> int main() { return SIGALRM; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean under "return signal"? In Linux signals are events, sent from one process to another.

In Linux, sys_kill or sys_tkill is to be used to send signals to some process or thread.

Arguments are:

```
sys_kill = 37
eax = 37
ebx = process ID (<-1, -1 and 0 have special meaning)
ecx = signal to send in your case SIGALRM = 14


sys_tkill = 238
eax = 238
ebx = the PID of the thread
ecx = signal ID
```

So, if you want to send a signal to your own process, you have to first get the process id and then to send signal:

```
mov  eax, sys_getpid    ; sys_getpid = 20
int  80h
mov  ebx, eax   ; PID to ebx

mov  eax, sys_kill
mov  ecx, SIGALRM
int  80h

mov  eax, sys_exit   ; sys_exit = 1
xor  ebx, ebx
int  80h
```

Comment: Thanks man, but how I can replace sys_getpid, sys_kill etc. with numbers? Its possible? My compiler can't compile code with that instructions.

Comment: @aso Don't use stupid copy/paste! Read my code carefully, the values of these constants are there! Also, read the link keltar posted in the above comment.